# Show that sigma algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ is the power set of $\Omega$

Tags: measure-theory

Prove that $\sigma(\{\{\omega\}:\omega \in \Omega\})=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ if $\Omega$ is atmost countable.

My idea is to show that each side is a subset of the other. Starting with $"\subset"$, we need to show that for any $X \in \sigma(\{\{\omega\}:\omega \in \Omega\})$ we have $X \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. However, I'm having trouble showing that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sure I edited it.

Comment: Trouble showing that $X \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$? Every subset of $\Omega$ is in $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$

Comment: Yes but I was confused since $X$ is in the sigma algebra of all subsets of $\Omega$?